# Istio not reporting https traces to Jaeger

Tags: kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks, envoyproxy

**Describe the bug**
We have a container running with envoy sidecar proxy with service/deployment for port 443 using Istio's own example: sample/https/nginx. We can curl the container to get nginx page just fine but see absolutely no traces in Jaeger for https calls. We see HTTP calls in Jaeger as soon as we switch the port to 80 in deployment/service

**Expected behavior**
We should see traces for both HTTP/HTTPS calls to the container.

**Steps to reproduce the bug:**

- create nginx config:

  ```
  https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/https/nginx-app.yaml
  ```
- Create nginx deployment :

  ```
  kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f nginx.yaml)
  ```
- `curl -kv https://service-ip` gives 200
- no traces in Jaeger for HTTPS

**Version**

```
istioctl version
Version: 1.0.2
GitRevision: d639408fded355fb906ef2a1f9e8ffddc24c3d64
User: root@66ce69d4a51e
Hub: gcr.io/istio-release
GolangVersion: go1.10.1
BuildStatus: Clean

[root@ip-10-147-5-150 ~]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2", GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-07T23:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.3", GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-28T20:13:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**Installation**

```
- kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/helm/helm-service-account.yaml
- helm init --service-account tiller
- helm install install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system
- helm upgrade --set tracing.enabled=true --set servicegraph.enabled=true --set global.configValidation=false istio install/kubernetes/helm/istio
```

**Environment**
- Running this within AWS EKS

**Cluster state**
- Attached 
[archite.tar.gz](https://github.com/istio/istio/files/2448004/archite.tar.gz)

Edit 1

**yaml for service - `jaeger-query` :**

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-02T02:32:23Z
  labels:
    app: jaeger
    chart: tracing-1.0.1
    heritage: Tiller
    jaeger-infra: jaeger-service
    release: istio
  name: jaeger-query
  namespace: istio-system
  resourceVersion: "5259733"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/services/jaeger-query
  uid: 6513eded-c5eb-11e8-860c-12504ba0df7c
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.20.14.251
  ports:
  - name: query-http
    port: 16686
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 16686
  selector:
    app: jaeger
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}`

**Deployment : `istio-tracing` :**

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-02T02:32:23Z
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: istio-tracing
    chart: tracing-1.0.1
    heritage: Tiller
    release: istio
  name: istio-tracing
  namespace: istio-system
  resourceVersion: "5259783"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/istio-system/deployments/istio-tracing
  uid: 65056099-c5eb-11e8-860c-12504ba0df7c
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jaeger
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: jaeger
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: beta.kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - amd64
            weight: 2
          - preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: beta.kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - ppc64le
            weight: 2
          - preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: beta.kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - s390x
            weight: 2
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: beta.kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - amd64
                - ppc64le
                - s390x
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HTTP_PORT
          value: "9411"
        - name: MEMORY_MAX_TRACES
          value: "50000"
        image: docker.io/jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.5
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 16686
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: jaeger
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9411
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 16686
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 5775
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 6831
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 6832
          protocol: UDP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 16686
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: 2018-10-02T02:32:23Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2018-10-02T02:32:23Z
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: 2018-10-02T02:32:23Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2018-10-02T02:32:27Z
    message: ReplicaSet "istio-tracing-ff94688bb" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1`

Comment: could you share Jaeger configuration you use in Kubernetes (deployments, services and so on)

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Ive used helm to install jaeger and it was basically running : `helm upgrade --set tracing.enabled=true`

Comment: Also my 443 port name is https dont know if that should be http- or with 1.x it supports https

Comment: But still, could you provide configurations from you cluster using commands `kubectl get deployment <name-of-your-deployment> -n <name-of-namespace-with-the deployment> -o yaml` and `kubectl get service <name-of-your-service> -n <name-of-namespace-with-the-service> -o yaml`

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev - done, check edit

Comment: Sorry for delay. Still it is hard to understand what is happening. Could you try to run `kubectl get deployment -o yaml --all-namespaces` and `kubectl get service -o yaml --all-namespaces` and provide us results.